# Audio activation causes webcam to freeze

Tags: webcam

I have purchased a new webcam and I have a problem. When I test audio or video, it all works. However, when I test the video with sound, the web browser (firefox) freezes.
Chromium freezes, but the video turns black after a few seconds.

I see an error in the dmesq report: **usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84**

I ran the usual commands and here are the results:

`sudo dmesg | grep uvcvideo`

```
[   83.658018] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[   83.667475] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[  196.343403] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  196.347417] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  196.351408] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  196.355402] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[  196.359401] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 1426.486880] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3124.540112] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3124.599578] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3133.727161] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3172.749702] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3172.753863] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3172.757814] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3172.761926] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3172.765849] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3223.919309] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3223.983470] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3239.217269] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3239.217279] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 3239.217284] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 3274.142225] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3274.146260] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3274.150207] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3274.154207] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3274.158324] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3628.393929] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3628.393943] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 3628.393951] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 3771.545947] Modules linked in: uvcvideo st snd_usb_audio snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib rfcomm algif_hash aes_neon_bs aes_neon_blk crypto_simd cryptd algif_skcipher af_alg hci_uart btqca btrtl btbcm btintel bnep vc4 drm_kms_helper cec snd_soc_core btsdio snd_compress bluetooth joydev input_leds ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_bcm2835(CE) snd_pcm_oss ecdh_generic ecc snd_mixer_oss brcmfmac snd_pcm brcmutil snd_seq_dummy snd_seq_oss bcm2835_isp(CE) bcm2835_codec(CE) bcm2835_v4l2(CE) cfg80211 snd_seq_midi bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(CE) snd_seq_midi_event v4l2_mem2mem videobuf2_vmalloc snd_rawmidi videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common crct10dif_ce snd_seq videodev v3d snd_seq_device mc gpu_sched raspberrypi_hwmon snd_timer snd vc_sm_cma(CE) fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt rpivid_mem uio_pdrv_genirq uio sch_fq tcp_bbr ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic xor xor_neon hid_generic usbhid raid6_pq libcrc32c spidev xhci_pci
[ 3771.546011]  xhci_pci_renesas phy_generic [last unloaded: uvcvideo]
[ 3786.468764] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3786.472766] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3786.476763] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3786.480730] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3786.484721] uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
[ 3796.599246] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3796.599253] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 3796.599256] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 4643.481104] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 4643.598508] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 4655.598321] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 4655.598338] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 4655.598346] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 6323.152611] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 6323.152626] uvcvideo: Forcing device quirks to 0x100 by module parameter for testing purpose.
[ 6323.152633] uvcvideo: Please report required quirks to the linux-uvc-devel mailing list.
[ 6510.278435] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
[ 6510.607359] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 6510.615009] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 7132.107013] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 7631.492749] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
```

`sudo dmesg`

```
[ 3124.599578] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3124.599585] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[ 3133.287821] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 3133.724035] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=636d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 3133.724054] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 3133.724065] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[ 3133.724074] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
[ 3133.724084] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: SN0001
[ 3133.727161] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:636d)
[ 3133.735160] input: USB 2.0 Camera: USB Camera as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input11
[ 3133.740339] usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 3134.005831] usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
[ 3134.021742] usb 1-1.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
```

`dmesg with chromium audit`

```
[ 8743.943123] kauditd_printk_skb: 516 callbacks suppressed
[ 8743.943134] audit: type=1400 audit(1646514839.275:2867): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/idVendor" pid=10114 comm="chrome" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 8743.943312] audit: type=1400 audit(1646514839.275:2868): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/interface" pid=10114 comm="chrome" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 8743.963541] audit: type=1400 audit(1646514839.295:2869): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/idVendor" pid=10114 comm="chrome" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

`sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 3938:1080  
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0c45:636d Microdia USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

My webcam: Xiaomi/Microdia IMILAB CMSXJ22A

My Linux: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)